# How do tags work in my profile

Tags: support, tags

Recently I have added few favorite tags as my friend suggested and after some time, I can see a list of values next to it.

When I click on [html](/questions/tagged/html), I can count a total of 10 votes (adding up-votes and subtracting down-votes).

```
13 + (-2) = 11??
```

But in my profile summary I see

```
7 html × 23
```

I cannot get my head around how this works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your favorite tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the numbers in the tags section of your profile the tooltip displays some additional information.  You've made 23 non-community wiki posts in the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag with a total score (upvotes - downvotes) of 7.

Comment: Small correction: the score is only for answers, not all posts, in this tag.

Comment: @RalZarek I think it's for all non-community wiki posts, both questions and answers.

Comment: Just take a look at the tool tip hovering over the score, it has a breakdown for questions and answers. The number before the tag is the same as the answer score. Or look at my meta profile, the only tags that have a non zero score are the ones from my one answer.